# How do I check that a particular lifecycle event method runs in a Doctrine event subscriber?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, lifecycle, doctrine-odm

I have a preUpdate event hook in an event listener and I want to write a test that just verifies that it gets executed when a particular document is updated. The only documentation I've been able to find about testing anything Doctrine-related was about testing query builders. I am new to Doctrine and this seems like a very simple thing to do but I really can't figure it out.

Comment: You can either do one of two things (or both): **1.** unit test the listener, mocking the objects you need to pass to the listener, and then just calling the function and making sure the entity updates. **2.** Write a functional test that actually performs a database operation that would trigger the listener, then poll the database value to make sure it changed to what you expected.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?  Would you prefer to functional test or unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `partial mock`. Lets say the class that has preUpdate hook is called Entity.

`$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Mock')->setMethods(array('preUpdate'))->getMock();`

This create an object for which only the preUpdate method is stubbed and you can write expectations to this method:

```
$mock->expects($this->once())->method('preUpdate');
// some code that triggers the hook
```

All other methods of the class will work as in the original class - they would not be overriden